# Getting minimum latitude of centroid geometries in a folder using Arcpy

Tags: python, arcpy

My goal is to print names of feature classes and corresponding minimum latitude of centroids of geometry for all shape files in a folder. In total I have 5 shapefiles and I'm trying to loop through them.

```
import arcpy
arcpy.env.overwriteOutput = True

arcpy.env.workspace = r"C:\Users\username\dataset_folder"

for z in arcpy.ListFeatureClasses():
    print(z)
```

I am able to print the names of these shapefiles but don't know how to get minimum latitude of centroids of geometry. What arcpy tool should I use to get these minimum latitude of centroids of geometries?

Comment: does it have to be arcpy? this kind of thing is *way* easier in geopandas

Comment: also, you'll probably get better answers at gis.stackexchange.com

Comment: I'm sorry I thought I was at gis.stackexhange.com, yes it has to be arcpy. I'm more familiar with geopandas but instructions ask for arcpy. 
I asked the same question there, not sure if I should delete this one?
Thank you again!

Answer (score 1):

You can use [SearchCursor and the SHAPE@XY](https://support.esri.com/en/technical-article/000011754) token to find these values.

```
#Creates a list of feature classes in the directory
feature_classes = []
for fc in arcpy.ListFeatureClasses():
    feature_classes.append(fc)

#Iterate through your feature classes
for fc in feature_classes:
    print(fc)
    
#Calculates the minimum centroid latitude of the features within each fc
    centroid_latitudes = []
    with arcpy.da.SearchCursor(fc, "SHAPE@XY") as cursor:
        for feature in cursor:
            centroid_latitudes.append(feature[0][1])
    print(min(centroid_latitudes))
```